# sniff mobile application to find whether packages sent to the third person

Tags: mobile, sniffer

I suspect that my messages via Viber are being sent to another person - because to my mobile have access a lot of people and it could be possible that somebody installed there some software  or configured it somehow to send my messages to another person

Is there a way to sniff this application and find whether my packages are send to some third person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you sniff mobile applications using a proxy system. You connect your phone to the proxy and then, obviously, all data runs through the computer/device which is running the proxy. Once the data is running through the proxy machine, you can simply open [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), or your favorite sniffing tool of choice and start recording the packets.

Personally I prefer using Charles for mobile packet sniffing. Both Charles and Fiddler have the built in ability to set up a proxy for your mobile device which makes them perfect for a task like this. (As far as I know, Wireshark does not offer this ability.) However, despite Fiddler's comparable ability, I prefer Charles because of its `HTTPS` decryption options. If Viber uses HTTPS, you can use Charles to decrypt it by installing the [Charles Proxy SSL Certificate](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) onto the device. (The certificate file can be found [here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/charles.crt).) Charles does come with a price though.

Charles is a paid application and it's not too cheap. As of the time of this posting, the program is $50 USD for 1 license. Unfortunately, Charles also does not offer free updates to new major versions. So if they released a new major version, you would have to pay for the upgrade unless you purchased within 3 months of the update. Their purchase page does say you only have to pay 40% of the price for the upgrade, but that is certainly not free. Even with all of this in mind though, I do still believe Charles Proxy is a good option.

To clarify, I am recommending Charles Proxy based on my own user experience. I use Charles Proxy fairly often to sniff applications and I have never had any problems.

Comment: I see. 50$ is rather cheap by the way...

Comment: $50.00 isn't much, but I think it's a little high for what it does. Considering the fact that they do not give free updates and I do not use it commercially, I feel as though it should be slightly lower. However, you are right, at the end of the day, $50.00 is not too much.